# Update to Monterey 12.3 fails: A snapshot is currently set to boot that is not the currently booted snapshot

Tags: macos, startup, apfs, monterey

[image: Error]

I have restarted the computer several times, but no help. The Disk Utility looks like this

[image: Disk Utility]

I once disabled the SIP following the guide in this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/kzzrub/tut_how_to_change_any_system_folder_finder_icon/), but re-enabled it afterward. And by executing the script in this thread, a snapshot was created. I wonder if it's this snapshot that causes the problem.

Comment: I disabled the SIP again and successfully upgraded to Monterey. But this is not a decent solution.